# C# Sockets ReceiveAsync No overload for method error

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, async-await

I am creating a Chatting application in a C# console app and just starting to learn about async tasks rather than just multi-threading which from my understanding is sort of outdated and better off using async.

I am using Microsoft's official documentation on sockets as a sort of guide to my own application because they use asynchronous programming but am getting an error.

Here is the code where I get the error:

```
    private async Task handleClientsAsync(Socket server)
    {
        Byte[] _buffer = new Byte[1024];
        Socket client = await server.AcceptAsync();
        while (true)
        {
            bool received = await client.ReceiveAsync(_buffer, SocketFlags.None); //This is the line with the error
        }
    }
```

The error is: "**No overload for method 'ReceiveAsync' takes '2' arguments.**" This confuses me because, on Microsoft's official documentation, they pass through the same parameters.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is a bit misleading. While there are no overloads that take 2 arguments, there are extension methods that do.

Some of the overloads for `ReceiveAsync()` were moved to extension methods between .NET 4.7 and .NET 4.7.1, in the [`System.Net.Sockets.SocketTaskExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.sockettaskextensions.receiveasync?view=netframework-4.7.1) class. As long as you have `using System.Net.Sockets;` at the top of your file, you can use those extension methods.

So why doesn't it work? Well, there never was an overload that accepted a plain byte array. But there was [an overload that accepted `Memory<Byte>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.receiveasync?view=net-7.0#system-net-sockets-socket-receiveasync(system-memory((system-byte))-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) and the `Memory<T>` class has [an operator to implicitly cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memory-1.op_implicit?view=net-7.0#system-memory-1-op-implicit(t())-system-memory((-0))).

That version of the overload was not moved to the extension methods. The [only equivalent one accepts `ArraySegment<Byte>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.sockettaskextensions.receiveasync?view=netframework-4.7.1), and `ArraySegment<T>` has no implicit casting operator. So you have to create the `ArraySegment<Byte>` yourself.

Although, even after you fix that, you'll get a compiler error warning that you can't implicitly cast an `int` to `bool`, since `ReceiveAsync()` has always returned an `int`.

You can change that line to this:

```
var received = await client.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(_buffer), SocketFlags.None); //This is the line with the error
```

The [`ArraySegment<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.arraysegment-1?view=netframework-4.7.1) struct does not copy the underlying array. It's just a way to refer to a section of an array. If you do not pass a range to the constructor, then it refers to the whole array.